# Network singleton

Tags: swift, architecture, closures, alamofire, dispatch

Currently I manage my network issues through a singleton:

```
class NetworkManager {

    public private(set) var queue: DispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "project.dispatchgroups", attributes: .concurrent, target: .main)
    public private(set) var dispatchGroup: DispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    private static var sharedNetworkManager: NetworkManager = {
        let networkManager = NetworkManager()

        return networkManager
    }()

    private init() {}

    class func shared() -> NetworkManager {
        return sharedNetworkManager
    }

    public func getData() { 
        dispatchGroup.enter()

        queue.async(group: dispatchGroup) {
            Alamofire.request("https://example.com/endpoint").responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let value):
                    let json = JSON(value)
                    DataAndDispatchManager.shared().data = json["result"]
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("error: ",error)
                }

                self.dispatchGroup.leave()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, when the request is done I save the returned data in an other singleton (DataAndDispatchManager)...

And when I use my network manager:

```
NetworkManager.shared().getUser()
NetworkManager.shared().dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
    let newData = DataAndDispatchManager.shared().data
}
```

My method has one big disadvantage:

I am using dispatchGroup.notify to notify myself about when request is finished, but there could be multiple requests... so it can turn into a bug.

My question: should I implement a closure?

Like: return data straight from `networkmanager` and call this method using a closure, so I can dismiss the `dispatchGroup.notify` part? Could anybody help me with this issue?